# Promises in a const function in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

This is my function

```
 const f = (value,err) => {
  if(!value === Number){
    throw err;
  }
  return (value);
}
```

Using promises I want to return an object of parameter **value** and after some wait it will return parameter in **number**. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A promise doesn't do anything in and of itself, and it doesn't make anything asynchronous in and of itself (other than that promise *reactions* are always asynchronous¹). A promise is just a standardized way to *report* the completion of something that's (potentially) asynchronous. So the literal answer to your question is: No, you can't use a promise to do that, not on its own. You'd have to combine it with something like `setTimeout` or similar.

Also note that `if (!value === Number)` is always false. It's evaluated like this: `!value`, negating the value of `value`, and then `x === Number`, which will always be false because there is no value that, when negated, turns into the `Number` function.

But for instance, if you wanted to check whether something is a number but not respond for 100ms:

```
const f = (value, err) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (typeof value !== "number") {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(value);
            }
        }, 100);
    });
};
```

Other than the promise, the two significant changes there are:

1. Using `setTimeout` to introduce asynchronousness, and
2. Changing the `if` condition to something that won't always be false (I may or may not have guessed correctly what you wanted there :-) )

---

¹ A *promise reaction* is a call to a `then`, `catch`, or `finally` callback registered on the promise. Here's an example of what I mean by "promise reactions are asynchronous:"

```js
console.log("Before creating the promise");
new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log("Inside the promise executor function");
    resolve(42);
})
.then(value => {
    console.log(`Promise reaction ran, value = ${value}`);
});
console.log("After creating the promise");
```

That code has this output:

```
Before creating the promise
Inside the promise executor function
After creating the promise
Promise reaction ran, value = 42
```

Notice that everything was synchronous except the call to the `then` callback (the promise reaction), which per specification is always done asynchronously, even if (as in this case) the promise is already settled when the reaction is added to it.

Comment: FWIW, I go into promises in some detail in Chapter 8 of my new book *JavaScript: The New Toys*, links in my profile if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks @TJCrowder. It helps. I was missing the setTimeout part.